# Authorization middleware in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am following this [link](http://scotch.io/quick-tips/js/node/route-middleware-to-check-if-a-user-is-authenticated-in-node-js) for a middleware pattern to check if a user is logged in expressjs: However I am running in to an issue. Suppose a user (Sam) is logged in and he is trying to edit/delete someone else's record, how can I add a middleware for that?

like for example: Sam, after loggin in, just types this in URL:

..../record/:random_id/edit

The middleware I wrote just checks for whether a user is logged in, which is true in this case. So he is able to edit the record.

One of the ways I am trying to resolve this issue is by doing two calls to the underlying database:

1. Get the data for the record/:random_id
2. See if the owner's id of the record is same as the guy who has logged in.
3. If yes, proceed with the edit
4. Else redirect the user to some other route

The problem with this approach is that this code needs to injected for so many routes. I am also  wondering if I can write a middleware which will avoid the extra trip to the database.

I looked in to passport.js, I could not use that for my scenario.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ...and different users will have different roles, granting them greater or lesser access to things like editing user accounts and so on?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_Based_Access_Control

Comment: The simplest implementation to extend a role based access control (typical in most of the systems) with owner attribute check. I think access control should be part of the domain logic, or it should be right before the domain logic. So you can reuse the code by multiple delivery mechanisms (REST, webapp, mobile, etc...)

Comment: that is correct @MatthewBakaitis.